# How to record position where fread() start to read?

Tags: udp, fread

I am implementing a RUDP with resend mechanism. I am using fread() to read a file and send the buffer. If the sender need to resend we need to know where the resend point is. I don't know how fread() could go back. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The current position is given by `ftell()`, and you can go back with `fseek().`

This is all documented.

Comment: Is it possible that the size of file is too large for return value of ftell() to hold?

Comment: Certainly, if the size does't fit into a `long`. Do you really have such an enormous file?